# Update only when not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update table tbl1 using table tbl2 but only if combination tbl2 (tbl2_col1,tbl2_col2) rows don't exist in tbl1. In this case I want to update 000006 both row to match those in tbl2.
I am getting an error on the query:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tbl1__A1B90E2508A9C3D2'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl1'. The duplicate key value is (000006, GG1).

What am I missing?

tbl2 :

```
tbl2_col1  tbl2_col2
000002     B
000003     C
000004     D
000005     Z
000006     GG1
000006     YY
```

tbl1:

```
tbl1_col1  tbl1_col2
000002     B
000003     C
000004     D
000005     Z
000006     GG
000006     YY
```

Query 1:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET
    tbl1_col2 = s.tbl2_col2
FROM tbl2 s
WHERE tbl1.tbl1_col1 = s.tbl2_col1
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE tbl1_col2 = s.tbl2_col2 AND tbl1_col1 = s.tbl2_col1
)
```

Comment: Change your update to a select initially while you debug.

Comment: Your update statement is all over the place, you are attempting to update a different table to that in you `FROM` clause which isn't how you do it. You need to update the same table as the from clause, potentially joining on other tables. As it stands I don't quite understand what your desired results are, so if you could add them please.

Comment: when you write `update tbl1 set ...` then your from must start with `from tbl1` and from there on you can join with other tables, or use a not exists or whatever

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, it is best to try it with a select first, to see what will be the outcome.
You can use a [right join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15) for this

```
select t1.tbl1_col1,
       t1.tbl1_col2,
       tbl2.tbl2_col1,
       tbl2.tbl2_col2
from   tbl1 t1
  right join tbl2 on t1.tbl1_col1 = tbl2.tbl2_col1
                 and t1.tbl1_col2 = tbl2.tbl2_col2 
where  t1.tbl1_col1 is null
```

this will get you this result, which actually are all rows in tbl2 that you don't have in tbl1

| tbl1_col1 | tbl1_col2 | tbl2_col1 | tbl2_col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | 000006 | GG1 |

So from here we can easily create our update statement, because we can simply use the query above in our update statement.

```
update t1
set    t1.tbl1_col2 = t.tbl2_col2
from   tbl1 t1
  join ( select --t1.tbl1_col1, 
                --t1.tbl1_col2,
                tbl2.tbl2_col1,
                tbl2.tbl2_col2
         from   tbl1 
           right join tbl2 on tbl1.tbl1_col1 = tbl2.tbl2_col1
                          and tbl1.tbl1_col2 = tbl2.tbl2_col2 
         where  tbl1.tbl1_col1 is null
       ) t on t1.tbl1_col1 = t.tbl2_col1
```

and after that tbl1 will look like this

| tbl1_col1 | tbl1_col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 000002 | B |
| 000003 | C |
| 000004 | D |
| 000005 | Z |
| 000006 | GG1 |
| 000006 | GG1 |

I also made a [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22e9320d8d4eb83d17fd669b630bdecc) here

**EDIT**

However, if you need this result

| tbl1_col1 | tbl1_col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 000002 | B |
| 000003 | C |
| 000004 | D |
| 000005 | Z |
| 000006 | GG1 |
| 000006 | YY |

then change the update query to this
(The only difference is the additional where clause at the end)

```
update t1
set    t1.tbl1_col2 = t.tbl2_col2
from   tbl1 t1
  join ( select tbl2.tbl2_col1,
                tbl2.tbl2_col2
         from   tbl1 
           right join tbl2 on tbl1.tbl1_col1 = tbl2.tbl2_col1
                          and tbl1.tbl1_col2 = tbl2.tbl2_col2 
         where  tbl1.tbl1_col1 is null
       ) t on t1.tbl1_col1 = t.tbl2_col1
where not exists ( select 1 
                   from   tbl2 
                   where  tbl2.tbl2_col1 = t1.tbl1_col1
                   and    tbl2.tbl2_col2 = t1.tbl1_col2
                 )
```

And again, here is a [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9800a68c33c5223f5edf14a1f9f92d0)